# Dockerコンテナ内でシェルが動く理屈がわかりません

Tags: linux, docker, shell, operating-system

[Dockerコンテナのシェルの中に入る - Qiita](https://qiita.com/__cooper/items/4740c24666299c366044)

`docker exec` にシェルを指定することでコンテナ内でシェルを操作できます。
このシェルはホストのものではなくコンテナのものだと思うのですが、シェルというのはOSのカーネルと対話するものですよね。たとえば`httpd`のイメージ等はWebサーバー用のイメージですからOSというものは内蔵されていないと思うのですが、なぜシェルが動くのでしょうか？

シェルが持つ代表的なコマンドが動くような最小限のOSがコンテナに内蔵されているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

("OSの`カーネル`と対話するものですよね" 辺りの文章の意図するところを理解できていませんが、タイトルの疑問に関しては)

単に`シェル`と呼ばれるプログラムがあらかじめコンテナイメージにインストールされているから動く、というだけです。

> `httpd`のイメージ

というのは

- https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd

のことだと思いますが、 このページからリンクされている[GitHub上のリポジトリ](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/)に登録されている`Dockerfile`を見ると、ベースは[Debian](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/6c8e82e20ecefc94c616439f15d14c4bb215b200/2.4/Dockerfile#L1)か[Alpine](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/f5ef4cc849a4ea7ed56e797b86ad06ccf9f93a9a/2.4/alpine/Dockerfile#L1)であることがわかります。
Debianであれば[`dash`](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell)が、Alpine Linuxであれば([busybox](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/How_to_get_regular_stuff_working#Shell_.40_commandline)の)[`ash`](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_Shell)が、 `/bin/sh` として入っています。

(ちなみに[`alpine`イメージ](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine)の`Dockerfile`は[これ](https://github.com/alpinelinux/docker-alpine/blob/v3.9/x86_64/Dockerfile)ですね。[`debian`](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian)は[スクリプトから生成している](https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts)っぽく、`Dockerfile`そのものはバージョン管理対象ではなさそうでした)

---

例えばAlpineのイメージで`bash`を使いたい場合、素の状態ではインストールされていないので利用できませんが、[こちらのイメージ](https://hub.docker.com/_/bash)のように[別途インストール](https://github.com/tianon/docker-bash/blob/master/5.0/Dockerfile)すれば利用できるようになる、というそれだけのことです。

使いたいプログラムが`シェル`と呼ばれるカテゴリに属しているかどうかは特に影響しない話かと思います。

---

> `シェル`が持つ代表的なコマンドが動くような最小限のOSがコンテナに内蔵されているのでしょうか？

`シェル`そのものが内蔵されています、というのが回答になります。

Comment: 何かしらのOS + httpd + 付属でシェル + （もしかしたらたまたま何かほかも入ってるかも）って構造になってる感じでしょうか？（しまった。まだDockerfileが読める段階にないので判断がつきません申し訳ありません）

Comment: "httpdのDockerイメージ"と聞いて期待するのは、`httpd`及び`httpd`を動作させるのに必要なツール群(シェルを含む)がインストールされたイメージ、かと考えます。なお、"OS"が指す箇所にもよるのですが、コンテナ型仮想化(Dockerのこと)は典型的なOS機能を含みません。"コンテナ 仮想化"みたいな用語で検索すると詳しい説明がヒットするかと思います(例えば[Microsoftの解説](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/containers-vs-vm))。

Comment: OSを含まないのであればここでいうDebianやAlpine等は何を指すのでしょうか？

Comment: (そもそも[Linuxディストリビューション](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%83%93%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3)にOSという概念は無いと思いますが(これもOSが何を指すのかにもよりますが、全部OSはLinux))例えばdebianなら、glibcのバージョンxxxを使っていてdashが利用できてパッケージ管理はaptで、一方alpineならmuslでashでapkで…といった風に利用可能なソフトウェアに違いがある、というのが1点。2点目は、おそらくdebianならDebianプロジェクトが、alpineならAlpine Linuxのプロジェクトがメンテナンスしているだろう、というメンテナの違いになります(必ずしもオフィシャルプロジェクトがメンテナであるとは限りませんが)。

Answer (score 3):

Docker のイメージにはユーザー空間向けのファイルやデータしか含まれません。カーネルイメージ (`/boot/vmlinuz*`) に相当するものは含まれません。コンテナ内のカーネルサービスはホスト OS 環境が提供するものを利用します。

コンテナとはホスト OS の各種リソース (プロセス ID、ファイルシステム、ネットワークなど) を分離してコンテナ専用の OS 環境を用意するものです。コンテナ内には OS のサービスとしてユーザー空間もカーネル空間は存在するし、当然どちらも利用できます。

`docker exec ...` すると Docker はコンテナを作成しますが、それはそのコンテナ用の名前空間 (`namespaces`(7)) を作成して隔離された OS 環境一式を作成し、その中で指定のコマンド (シェルなど) を起動しているに過ぎません。

コンテナ内でシェルが利用できるかどうかはコンテナイメージ内のファイル構成に依ります。シェルそのもの (`/bin/sh` など) のほか、シェルの実行に必要な共有ライブラリ等が存在すれば利用できるでしょう。それらを含めないコンテナイメージも作成可能です。

Comment: "`docker exec ...` すると" は、より正確には、 "`docker run ...` すると" なのではないかな、と思っています。

Answer (score 2):

なるべく易しい言葉で説明してみたいと思います。

大事なのは、シェルというのは C 言語（あるいは他の言語でも）で書ける普通のプログラムである、ということです。OS （カーネル）から見ればシェルは特別でも何でもなく、 `ls` や、 `httpd` と同列のプログラムなのです。シェルのプログラムとしては代表的には `bash` 、他には `sh`、`csh`、`dash` などがあります（これらの区分については若干注意が必要ですがここでは略します）。

言いかえるならば、シェルというのは、他のプログラムを起動するために使うプログラムということです。シェルの中でシェルを起動することもできます。シェルが入れ子になっている回数は SHLVL という環境変数に入っていますから、以下のようなことができます。

```
$ echo $SHLVL
1
$ bash         # A: 新しくシェルを起動
$ echo $SHLVL  # 見分けがつかないがここは A のシェルの中
2
$ <ctrl+d>     # A のシェルを抜ける
$ echo $SHLVL  # 元のシェルに戻ってきた
1
```

ご質問の点について： シェルも `httpd` も同じプログラムですから、Docker の中で同じように実行することができます。そこでご質問の問題については、Docker がどのようにプログラムを起動しているか、という点に整理できるのではないかと思います。残念ながら、その問題は Docker の基本的な設計に関わるところで、そもそも OS が何をしているかという点から始めて順を追って理解していかねばならないような非常に大きなテーマです。

ここでは「Docker はプログラムの実行環境を抽象化しているものだ」というふわっとした説明でひとまずは納得していただければ、と思います。

Answer (score 1):

「OSのカーネルと対話」というのはシステムコールと呼ばれるものだと思いますが、
コンテナ内部のプロセスも、システムコールはホストOSのカーネルが処理します。
(これはホストOS上にあるプロセスのシステムコールをホストOSのカーネルが処理するのと同様です)

ちなみに質問にあるシェルに限らず、インストールされるコマンドやアプリケーションもすべてシステムコールを処理するカーネルが無いと動作することが出来ません。

※コメントを受け追記

ホストOSから見ると、ホスト上で動作する通常プロセスもコンテナ内に入っているプロセスも両方共管理下に置かれていてそれほど大きな区別がありません。この点はVirtualBoxなどのOSをまるごと仮想化する場合との違いだと思います。
もちろんコンテナなどの隔離環境で動作しているかどうかを区別する情報は持っていて、実際の動作で処理を区別することはあるかもしれませんが、カーネルは基本的にはコンテナかどうかに関わらずシステムコールが呼ばれたらその指示に基づいた動作をするだけです。

Comment: コンテナ内にもディレクトリ構造があります。ディレクトリ構造はシステムコールではないと思うのですが（ファイルシステム？）、このあたりはどうなのでしょうか？（質問に明記しておらず申し訳ありません）コンテナ内のシェルでls等ディレクトリ構造等が参照できるはずです

Comment: プロセス(シェルも含みます)が行うさまざまなファイル操作も最終的にはシステムコールを呼ぶことによって行われています。(回答の繰り返しになり恐縮ですが、)それはホストOSのカーネルによって処理されます。

Comment: なるほど私はOS自体を作ったことがないので、表面的なことしかわかっていなかったようです。

Comment: 私もOS自体を作ったことは無いです。
どちらかというとプロセスから見てカーネルとどういうやり取りをするかに関するところなのかなと思います。
疑問の解消になるかわかりませんが、カーネルからみたプロセスの見え方について回答に追記しました。